# Run a Command Upon Exiting a Filetype

Tags: autocmd

I know you can run a command upon entering a filetype with...

```
au! Filetype foo echo "bar"
```

but what can I use to run this command when I leave this filetype?

Answer (score 1):

There's no such event as "leaving" FileType. It's just an option that could be set to another value effectively triggering yet another FileType event.

For user convenience, standard runtime supports buffer-locals `b:undo_ftplugin` and `b:undo_indent` to `:execute` them before new ftplugin/indent setting applied (provided that such variables exist). So they are used to undo anything done by the previous ftplugin/indent module.